# rrdcgi double graph problem: Unable to connect to rrdcached: Permission denied

Tags: rrdtool

I try to draw two graphs, but the second one fails to draw with the message "Unable to connect to rrdcached: Permission denied". The output looks like this:

```
+--------------------+
|  the first graph   |
+--------------------+
[ERROR Unable to connect to rrdcached: Permission denied]
```

If i make a mistake in the parameters of the first graph, the output looks like this

```
[ERROR 'EAREA' is not a valid function name in EAREA:cel1#00a000:in] 
+--------------------+
|  the second graph  |
+--------------------+
```

What am i doing wrong? apache2 web server if this is important.

The script:

```
#!/usr/bin/rrdcgi

<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>test</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<table border=0 width=500>
<tr><td>

<RRD::GRAPH ../htdoc/tmp/images/first.png
       --imginfo '<IMG SRC=/tmp/images/%s WIDTH=%lu HEIGHT=%lu >'
       --lazy --start -2d --end now --width 600 --height 150
DEF:cel1='../collectd.rrd/rrd/test/snmp/if_octets-Ethernet1_0_10.rrd':rx:AVERAGE
AREA:cel1#00a000:"in"
>

</td></tr>
<tr><td>

<RRD::GRAPH ../htdoc/tmp/images/second.png
       --imginfo '<IMG SRC=/tmp/images/%s WIDTH=%lu HEIGHT=%lu >'
       --lazy --start -5y --end now --width 600 --height 150
DEF:cel2='../collectd.rrd/rrd/test/snmp/if_octets-Ethernet1_0_10.rrd':tx:AVERAGE
AREA:cel2#00a000:"out"
>

</td></tr>
</table>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a solution with rrdcached but there is a way to disable its use:

`<RRD::SETENV RRDCACHED_ADDRESS  "" >`